# Best way to deal with connection errors when connecting to web services

Tags: android

I have an android app that sends and receives information from a vb.net web service. Things are great if there is a solid and fast internet connection but otherwise, everything becomes shaky.

The process goes like this:
1. The app sends information (such as an ID)
2. The web service returns information based on the ID (like a name)
3. The app updates the database within it based on the info sent by the web service.

The problem comes when the internet connection is weak. What happens is the app still sends the information but sometimes the information being received is incomplete or a connection timeout occurs; and the app still goes into step 3.

The app shouldn't be updating the database because the transaction was either incomplete or with errors. Any ideas on how I should go about this?

I was thinking of making sure that the transaction is complete before updating the DB. So the web service also sends a sort of 'complete' signal to tell the app that it's time to update the DB. Is this a good idea or is there a better way to go into this?

As for the connection timeout issue any way to catch that? I've seen a catch for the timeout but are there other alternatives which are better? Also if the connection times out what happens to the data that was sent and received?

Much obliged

Comment: which way to connect you use? the Google library volley has a nice error handling and is easy to use for communication with webservices... many good tutorials are there...

Comment: I use SOAP in an async task to connect to the vb.net web service. I'll take a look at those. Thanks